# OpenCSV reads in additional byte value together with first line's first value together in Java

Tags: java, spring, csv, character-encoding, opencsv

I was working on a project where we use OpenCSV to read in CSV files and fill up a database with them at start. I noticed that there is a strange thing, that in certain cases a given identifier value can not be queried. During debugging I found that OpenCSV does not read up the CSV correctly.

Let's say that I have the following CSV file:

```
01;foo
02;bar
...
```

The first line in the example is the first line in the real CSV file as well. The file is encoded in UTF-8. The following code is used to read in the value:

```java
 try (CSVReader csvReader = CSVUtils.createCSVReader(masterDataCSVPath, csvDelimiter)) {
            List<String[]> masterData = csvReader.readAll();
        }
```

The code creating the `csvReader`:

```java
    static private CSVParser createCSVParser(String CSVDelimiter) {
        return new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(CSVDelimiter.charAt(0)).build();
    }

    static public CSVReader createCSVReader(String CSVPath, String CSVDelimiter) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(CSVPath)).withCSVParser(createCSVParser(CSVDelimiter)).build();
    }
```

When I read in the CSV file with the following code, during debug I get the following byte values for `01`:

[image: Wrong CSV data]

However if I change my CSV file to (notice the newline at the top):

```
01;foo
02;bar
...
```

The read-in data becomes:

[image: CSV data with newline at the beggining]

In this case "all is good", if I remove the first item in my `masterData` list, I can read in the values "properly". However, this is not a clean solution:

- It begs the question: *Why does this happen?*
- Also, I do not think that we should work around the problem rather than solving it. This is only provided to work if there a newline at the beginning of my source CSV.

So I kindly ask for help, that how can this be mitigated?

Comment: My guess is that this is the `UTF-8` `BOM` issue. I think there is a setting that you can set to tell `OpenCSV` that a  `UTF-8` `BOM` exists.  I have not worked with `OpenCSV` in a while, so I could be wrong.  If this is the case, one thing you can do is use `NotePad++`  to remove the `BOM`.

Comment: @Sedrick thank you very much. This was the problem. I have resolved it by using Apache's implementation for reading in files with BOM. I will answer the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an OpenCSV specific problem, but rather that `FileReader` reads in the BOM in the UTF encoded file. This is kind of unexpected, but it makes sense, as there is no context for `FileReader` that it should excludes those bytes.

The solution would be to either manually remove it, or - in my case - use a library to make sure it is excluded. I wrote the following utility class:

```
public class CSVUtils {

private static CSVParser createCSVParser(final String CSVDelimiter) {
    return new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(CSVDelimiter.charAt(0)).build();
}

private static  BOMInputStream versatileBOMInputStreamGenerator(final InputStream inputStream) {

    return new BOMInputStream(inputStream, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16LE,
            ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32LE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32BE);
}


public static  CSVReader createCSVReaderFromFile(final String CSVPath, final String CSVDelimiter) throws FileNotFoundException {
    return new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(
            versatileBOMInputStreamGenerator(new FileInputStream(CSVPath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .withCSVParser(createCSVParser(CSVDelimiter)).build();
}

public static  CSVReader createCSVReaderFromString(final String content, final String CSVDelimiter) {
    byte[] contentBytes = content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(
            versatileBOMInputStreamGenerator(new ByteArrayInputStream(contentBytes)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            .withCSVParser(createCSVParser(CSVDelimiter)).build();
}
```

}

All I have to do is use these created `CSVReader` objects later where needed. As you can see, it uses some dependencies, which can be imported with

```
import org.apache.commons.io.ByteOrderMark;
import org.apache.commons.io.input.BOMInputStream;
```

These dependencies can be added to the project via the POM as follows:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
```